# Encyclopedic dictionary of Mathematics

Tags: reference-request, reference-works

I'm looking for a complete dictionary about Mathematics, after searching a lot I found only this one [http://www.amazon.com/Encyclopedic-Dictionary-Mathematics-Second-VOLUMES/dp/0262090260/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1323066833&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262090260) .

I'm looking for a book that can give me a big picture, well written with a clever idea in mind from the author, a big plus can be the presence of railroad diagram or diagram with logic connections between the elements.

Comment: I am wondering whether this "complete" book exists or not.

Answer (score 7):

[Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/)

> The Encyclopedia of Mathematics wiki is an open access resource designed specifically for the mathematics community. The original articles are from the online Encyclopaedia of Mathematics, published by Kluwer Academic Publishers in 2002. With more than 8,000 entries, illuminating nearly 50,000 notions in mathematics, the Encyclopaedia of Mathematics was the most up-to-date graduate-level reference work in the field of mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

I have always been fond of [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/), though I have seen it critiqued for not being accurate in some articles. It is also available in [print](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584883472).

Comment: It's available in print, but 1. it's a bit outdated; and 2. CRC and Weisstein have a sorry history regarding the production of the book (he basically got shafted). Search around for the gory details...

Answer (score 0):

You might first try the updated version of the book you mention, the [*Encyclopedia of Mathematics*](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Main_Page) which is freely available via the quoted link. Then, since this encyclopedia is very weak on applied mathematics you could have a try with Engquist (ed): *Encyclopedia of Applied and Computational Mathematics*. This will give you a cross-disciplinary overview of mathematics.