# Is there such a thing as a mathematical thesaurus?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, proof-writing

I want this for two reasons:

1. When writing proofs, I am constantly in need of synonyms of basic words like thus, there exists, for all, such as, contains, etc.
2. A lot of mathematical concepts have multiple names, e.g. abelianization vs derived quotient, vanishes vs goes to $0$, and so on.

A big list of either of these types of synonyms would help improve the flow of my mathematical writing.  Also, the latter case would familiarize me with alternative terminology I may run into later.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: I'm not aware of one, but someone (maybe you?) should make one!

Comment: @Suugaku if this question doesn't turn up with anything maybe I'll make a wiki or something.

Comment: Perhaps some of the [Dictionaries and resources for translation of mathematical terminology](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164553/) can be useful for finding synonyms, too. (Quite often Wikipedia can do the job.) You said that you are interested in this because you want to improve the style of your proofs. So these two posts can be interesting for you: [What are or where can I find style guidelines for writing math?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14189/); [Book about technical and academic writing](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/).... (cont)

Comment: (cont)... In particular, Trzeciak's book has concrete examples of sentences and phrases useful in various situations.

Answer (score 10):

There is a very comprehensive (at least very *long*!) "Handbook of Mathematical Discourse" which you can find [here](http://www.abstractmath.org/Handbook/handbook.pdf).

Under the various topics they list some synonyms, but I can't vouch for its completeness or accuracy. Also, it is more of a dictionary or encyclopedia than a pure thesaurus.

EDIT: [Another question on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88478/encyclopedic-dictionary-of-mathematics) asks a similar question and one of the answers points to [this online encyclopedia](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Main_Page). It seems, however, that this one might be of limited use as a thesaurus. After a few tries it looks like synonyms are rarely included.

Comment: Wow.  Not exactly what I was looking for but still a great find.  Gonna be using that one.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Yea, it also seems that the intended audience is advanced undergraduates and early grads. Maybe more use as a pedagogical tool.

Comment: The link to the handbook in the answer is dead, but http://abstractmath.org/Books/handbkhyper.pdf works. (I got it from [here](http://www.cwru.edu/artsci/math/wells/pub/abouthbk.html).)

Comment: abstractmath.org also looks to be dead. I'll just leave a link to the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160611124020/http://www.abstractmath.org/Handbook/handbook.pdf), hopefully this one never disappears.